# Spring Framework 4 & Apache Tiles 3 - no such definition error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat, apache-tiles

I have had a bit of a look around and can't seem to find a post with the scenario that i've come across.

I have written a small web app that utilises Spring MVC 4 and apache tiles 3. I am using apache tiles as I wanted to create a master page template in order to keep the application look and feel constant. I have been developing this in eclipse and running it on and apache 8 server through the IDE. This has all been running absolutely fine through eclipse and the templating was working well.

When I have exported the project as a .war file and run it up on the same apache 8 server outside of the IDE I am receiving the following stack trace when trying to view pages that use the tiles templating:

```
    2: <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
3: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
4:     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
5: <tiles:insertDefinition name="defaultTemplate">
6:  <tiles:putAttribute name="body">
7: <div class="body"> 
8:  Hi <c:out value="${uacc_fname}"></c:out> <c:out value="${uacc_sname}"></c:out> welcome to the home page!!


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.SouthC.Messwich.WebApp.FilterAuthCheck.doFilter(FilterAuthCheck.java:80)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: Unable to find the definition 'defaultTemplate'
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:218)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertDefinitionModel.renderDefinition(InsertDefinitionModel.java:132)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertDefinitionModel.execute(InsertDefinitionModel.java:99)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertDefinitionTag.doTag(InsertDefinitionTag.java:254)
    org.apache.jsp.webapp.home_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertDefinition_005f0(home_jsp.java:105)
    org.apache.jsp.webapp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.SouthC.Messwich.WebApp.FilterAuthCheck.doFilter(FilterAuthCheck.java:80)

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /webapp/home.jsp        at line 5
```

I have checked that the server can definately read the tiles.xml definition file as when I remove it from the location that it is specified in, a different error comes up on start up. Below are my configuration files:

servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.test.WebApp"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
      <property name="prefix" value="" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      <property name="order" value="1" />
   </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Messwich</display-name> 
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>testWebApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testhWebApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

tiles.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

        <tiles-definitions>

    <definition id="defaultTemplate" name="defaultTemplate" template="/template/defaultTemplate.jsp">
        <put-attribute id="header" name="header" value="/template/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute id="footer" name="footer" value="/template/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Any help with this would be much appriciated, I'm just not sure why it works through the IDE but not when it is exported.

Thanks in advance.

Phil

Answer (score 0):

```
<value>/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
```

Is this correct? Often it's /WEB-INF/tiles.xml

Comment: Hi mck, thanks for your response. I have tried both ways and both work in the IDE but not when I deploy the app as a .war file. I'm really struggling to find any answers on the net. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Complete Tiles dependency with all supported technologies is achievable with the following      dependency declaration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Basic Tiles dependency with only servlet support can be added this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

If you need a dependency to Tiles JSP support, declare the dependency this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am answering something a little old but maybe the right solution, and it could help others.

I think that the problem is that you have given order to the InternalResourceViewResolver and  you forgot to add the view resolver of the tiles that could be something like this:

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
</beans:bean>
```

Giving to the other order value = 2